# End-2-End Testing outside angularjs

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, ui-testing, end-to-end

I'm looking for a way to test an app or a website, which is **not** based on angularjs, on real browsers and real devices. I found [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/), but CasperJS only runs with headless browsers.

Are there test-runner/testing-framework combinations out there which support:

- grunt
- all major browser (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE)
- headless browsers (PhantomJS)
- (optional) simulate touch gestures

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would choose protractor. I know its main target is angular, but it works fine without angular as well. It has nice shortcut features. We use it to test non-angular sites and it looks stable enough. Otherwise it is based on webdriverjs, and it can work with phantomjs as well.

There is a good starter setup: https://github.com/angular/angular-seed

And this page can help to tune it for your requirements:

http://ng-learn.org/2014/02/Protractor_Testing_With_Angular_And_Non_Angular_Sites/

And the main urls:

- https://github.com/angular/protractor
- https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs

I didn't test the phantomjs part, but google says it should be fine.

About main browsers Protractor can connect to Saucelabs as well.
http://www.saucelabs.com/

And they have 301 different Device/OS/Browser Platforms at now. https://saucelabs.com/platforms

Answer (score 1):

[Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org) is certainly the most widely used test automation tool that meets your requirements. I personally used [Sahi](http://sahi.co.in) most of the times which does the same but afaik has no grunt integration.